# What is the meaning of privilege user types in class diagrams?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I want to know what is the meaning of "privilege user type " in class diagram. I got a question as "Enhance the class diagram according to privilege user types". I did browse through google and didn't get an idea.

Comment: Go and ask your instructor what he/she meant with that.

Comment: Okay Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It has no specific meaning that I am aware of in UML Class Diagrams as specified by OMG. I imagine your professor is asking you to design a mechanism through which End-User privileges (e.g. access rights to behaviour and data) can be controlled, in your class model. As TK says, check with them.